# catx function where columns are null

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro, proc-sql

I am working with catx function in sas enterprise guide.
When I want to concatenate 2 columns I am using

```
catx('-',column1,column2)
```

It works fine but when both column1 and column2 are null it still gives '-' as output

How to restrict this, if both are null just give me null

Comment: Do you also what it to add the hyphen when only one of the values is missing?

Comment: What do the values show when you format the columns with $HEX32. ?  If it's not 2020202020... then you have control characters in your values.

Answer (score 2):

`CATX` will return a null (blank) value if all concatenation values are blank.

If your result is appearing as `-` then your values probably are an invisible non-printable character such as tab, newline or carriage return.

Look ma, no dash!

```
data have;
s=' ';
t=' ';
u = catx('-',s,t);
run;

proc sql;
  create table result as select s,t,catx('-',s,t) as u from have;
quit;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

```
/* Using PROC SQL */
proc sql;
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN column1 IS NOT NULL OR column2 IS NOT NULL THEN catx('-', column1, column2)
            ELSE NULL
        END AS concatenated_columns
    FROM your_table;
quit;
```